# Qthreading In Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I am Working on an app where you enter an amazon product URL and phone number and it texts you when that item is in stock. I am working with the URL and I am going to have it so that when you press the start button it goes to the URL you entered and checks if it is out of stock but when I press the start button the program crashes and says not responding. here is my code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import threading
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Ui_AmazonStockCheck(object):
        def setupUi(self, AmazonStockCheck):
            AmazonStockCheck.setObjectName("AmazonStockCheck")
            AmazonStockCheck.resize(804, 617)
            AmazonStockCheck.setWindowTitle('Stocker')
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(AmazonStockCheck)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.urlBox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.urlBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 161, 51))
            self.urlBox.setObjectName("urlBox")
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Bebas Neue")
            font.setPointSize(20)
            self.phonenumberBox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.phonenumberBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 90, 161, 51))
            self.phonenumberBox.setObjectName("phonenumberBox")
            self.producturl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.producturl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 50, 111, 31))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Bebas Neue")
            font.setPointSize(20)
            self.producturl.setFont(font)
            self.producturl.setObjectName("producturl")
            self.phonenumber = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.phonenumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 60, 131, 31))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Bebas Neue")
            font.setPointSize(20)
            self.phonenumber.setFont(font)
            self.phonenumber.setObjectName("phonenumber")
            self.startbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.startbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 160, 141, 41))
            self.startbutton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.onclick(self.urlBox.text()))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Bebas Neue")
            font.setPointSize(16)
            self.startbutton.setFont(font)
            self.startbutton.setObjectName("startbutton")
            self.abouttext = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.abouttext.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 240, 601, 231))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Bebas Neue")
            font.setPointSize(28)
            self.abouttext.setFont(font)
            self.abouttext.setObjectName("abouttext")
            AmazonStockCheck.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(AmazonStockCheck)
            self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 804, 21))
            self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
            AmazonStockCheck.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
            self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(AmazonStockCheck)
            self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
            AmazonStockCheck.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

            self.retranslateUi(AmazonStockCheck)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AmazonStockCheck)

        def retranslateUi(self, AmazonStockCheck):
                _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
                AmazonStockCheck.setWindowTitle(_translate("AmazonStockCheck", "MainWindow"))
                self.producturl.setText(_translate("AmazonStockCheck", "Product Url"))
                self.phonenumber.setText(_translate("AmazonStockCheck", "Phone Number"))
                self.startbutton.setText(_translate("AmazonStockCheck", "Start"))
                self.abouttext.setText(_translate("AmazonStockCheck", "App developed by Gabriel Zebersky Beta Version"))


        def onclick(self, url):
            headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', "Pragma": "no-cache"}
            page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            while True:
                if soup.find(id='outOfStock'):
                    print('NOT IN STOCK')
                    time.sleep(2)
            else:
                print('IN STOCK')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    AmazonStockCheck = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_AmazonStockCheck()
    ui.setupUi(AmazonStockCheck)
    AmazonStockCheck.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I saw that maybe threading might work. Is there any way I could use Qthread or Qthreadpool to fix this problem?

Comment: You want to separate UI and program classes. The program class should inherit `QWidget` or `QMainWindow` and have a proper `__init__` for the things that you are doing in the main currently. In that class, you want `self.ui = Ui_AmazonStockCheck()` and `self.ui.setupUi(parent=self)`. The `onclick` method should be in the program class while the UI class should stay "inert".

Comment: Not only they should be separate classes, they should be on separate files also, as the UI generated from pyuic is most likely going to be overwritten whenever you need to change something in Designer (and those files should **NEVER** be modified by hand). Read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows will tell you that your application (supposedly) crashed because it has hang. What it means is that the code is not processing any event (so the app is frozen), probably because it is stuck doing something else.

In your application, when you click on the button, the `onclick` method gets called. But this function never returns because it will indefinitely check the item availability (due to `while True` with no `break`).
What is does is that the Main Thread (which in PyQt handles the GUI) gets stuck in this method after the buttons gets clicked.

Indeed, you should use a thread for that : the auxiliary thread will get stuck in a loop, but the Main Thread will still be free to run and handle the events.

Here is a minimal example of a worker that does not block the main thread :

```py
import random
import time
import typing

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_AmazonStockCheck(object):
        def setupUi(self, AmazonStockCheck):
            AmazonStockCheck.resize(804, 617)
            AmazonStockCheck.setWindowTitle('Stocker')
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(AmazonStockCheck)
            self.urlBox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.urlBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 161, 51))
            self.startbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start", self.centralwidget)
            self.startbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 160, 141, 41))
            self.startbutton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.onclick(self.urlBox.text()))
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AmazonStockCheck)

            layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            layout.addWidget(self.urlBox)
            layout.addWidget(self.startbutton)
            self.centralwidget.setLayout(layout)
            AmazonStockCheck.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        def onclick(self, url):
            print(f"starting to check availability for {url!r}")
            self.checker = AvailabilityChecker(url, self.centralwidget)
            print("checker has started")
            self.checker.availability_update.connect(
                lambda is_available: print(f"received update: available={is_available}")
            )


class AvailabilityChecker(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, url, parent: QtCore.QObject):
        super().__init__(None)  # a QObject with a parent can not be moveToThread'd
        self.url = url

        self._thread = QtCore.QThread(parent)
        self.moveToThread(self._thread)
        assert QtCore.QThread.currentThread() != self._thread  # we are still running in the caller's thread
        self._thread.started.connect(self.check_indefinitely)
        self._thread.start()

    def check_indefinitely(self) -> typing.NoReturn:
        assert QtCore.QThread.currentThread() == self._thread  # we are now running in our dedicated thread
        while True:
            is_available = (random.randint(0, 10) == 9)
            if is_available:
                print("AVAILABLE")
            else:
                print("NOT AVAILABLE")
            self.availability_update.emit(is_available)
            time.sleep(2)

    availability_update = QtCore.pyqtSignal([bool])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_AmazonStockCheck()
    ui.setupUi(main_window)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can see that you can still use the GUI while the worker, in its own thread, endlessly checks for the availability (I just `random` for convenience).

I simply connected a lambda to the signal that the worker emits, but you should connect it to a method of your GUI to update its state (change a color, a text, whatever).

Also, the thread runs endlessly, so your application does not exit cleanly. You should consider having a slot on your worker to change a boolean `should_stop`, and change the loop into `while not should_stop`, so that you can call the slot to make your thread exit shortly after.

But I hope you can understand the gist of my answer. Yes, use an object in a thread (a "worker"). Use signals to communicate between your worker and the GUI. There are a lot of examples and documentation about how to do that.

If it suits you, I found that making the worker class also inherit QRunnable (in addition to QObject for signal/slots) makes possible to delegate all the threading to a QThreadPool, which simplifies much of the code.

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting assert QtCore.QThread.currentThread() == self._thread  # we are now running in our dedicated thread
AssertionError idk why.

Comment: @Gaboni I reran my example and it works fine. Can you confirm that ? I think the problem is how you added this code to yours. The method `check_indefinitely` must not be called directly, it is only executed when the thread (to which the object was `moveToThread`'d to) started. That the assert failed looks like you called the method directly. Instantiating the class suffices, you should not call the method after that.